# Would a Tip Jet be more efficient or practical the bigger/longer it gets?

Tags: efficiency, rotorcraft, tip-jets

In summary, a [tip jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip_jet) is a jet nozzle at the tip of some helicopter rotor blades, used to spin the rotor without much torque.

[image]
[Source of the picture](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252026659_Geometry_design_model_of_a_tip-jet_reaction-drive_rotor_based_on_coupling_analysis) (it is an article)

One of the types of Tip Jet is using a compressor to inject air and fuel in a duct (as shown in the image), but even without the compressed air, if you elongate the rotor enough, in the right speed, the air could be compressed and mixed with the fuel (and thus, create thrust) without the need of an external compressor.

But what made me make this question was this [video](https://youtu.be/yrc632oilWo) explaining about the SpinLaunch, where it is explained that the tips get even more heavier the faster it spins. Also as shown in this [video](https://youtu.be/iA6enVQvNgw), when you rotate a hollow "duct" fast enough, it starts to suck air.

In summary, what I could understand of the centrifugal force in a rotor is that the more it accelerates, the "heavier" the tips get, and thus, the air could be compressed with this phenomena.

So, I thought it could make sense to make something like this, but I don't know if the speeds with the air friction would allow the rotor to spin fast enough to be able to compress air and fuel.

---

### The question:

**Would a longer tipjet be more efficient than the previously made helicopter-sized Tip Jets?**

With all this in mind, and with the fact that tip-jets were already explored enough through the years, it would be possible to answer this question?

Or even if you were able to do that, a smaller helicopter would be more efficient anyway?

Comment: Judging by the [Fairey Rotodyne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairey_Rotodyne), tip jets are pretty efficient at deafening people. "From two miles away it would stop a conversation." said Hawker's chief test pilot.